# Online Dictionary that shows "Word Family"?

Tags: discussion

I want an online dictionary where I will look for a word and it will show the definition with the word family.

For example: If I search "Enigma"
It will show the definition along with the other parts of speech; enigma, enigmatic, enigmatical

Comment: Wiktionary should do it for you. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enigma.

Comment: Good paper dictionaries used to do this. The online OED's interface allows this either through the definition itself or through the alphabetized 'nearby' word list in the right pane. The OED is available free to those with a public library ID number in most public libraries in the US and the UK (but you may have to get to the OED through your library's website).

Comment: What research have you done? Which online dictionaries did you look at to see if they offer what you're looking for? Here's a useful link to find a range of dictionaries that define a given word: https://www.onelook.com